# Inserting NULL for NUMBER column

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I am trying to insert NULL value for my NUMBER column in H2 database. 
In my Java model the corresponding value is Long (not primitive). Now, I am aware how JDBC driver inserts 0 for nulls if not specified, but I do exactly that.
My DAO layer is in Spring, and for this exact column I am mapping its value in this manner.

```
if(user.getDefaultNumber() == null){
      map.addValue("defaultNumber", user.getDefaultNumber(), Types.NULL);
}else{
      map.addValue("defaultNumber", user.getDefaultNumber());
}
```

However, this does not seem to be working. I have tracked it deep into Spring Core classes, and null value for my object is there, but somewhere it still gets turned to 0.

Can someone please help me, this is bugging me for days.

Comment: Types.Integer should do the trick

Comment: @eduyayo Thank you on your advice, this worked for me. I will post this as an answer with some addition for my case specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was adding Types.Integer. I am still not sure why it did not work with Types.NULL but I will investigate. For now this is the solution

```
if(user.getDefaultNumber() == null){
      map.addValue("defaultNumber", user.getDefaultNumber(), Types.INTEGER);
}else{
      map.addValue("defaultNumber", user.getDefaultNumber());
}
```

Also, it is very important to map it properly when reading from DB. JDBC will read NULLs from database, but it will still insert 0 in Java's attribute. So, if reading is not handled properly as well, it might leave an impression that the problem persists even though the writing part is actually OK.

Answer (score 0):

Please try PreparedStatement to save null value in integer column

```
pst.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not possible, the architecture is quite large and it has been set already to use value mapping with Spring. Therefore, it was not an option to directly call PreparedStatements, but advice from comment above did the trick. Thanks anyway